# Comparing values in Data Table in c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I have loaded Two Excel files in two datable now i have to check that the Specific value of column one  of DataTable1 exist in specific cloumn of DataTable 2 or not. I have only one output in rich Text Box which is wrong . What should i do

string connectionStringold = Application.StartupPath + "\Language-Resources-3.0" + ".xls";

```
        string connstrold = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=" + connectionStringold + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
        OleDbConnection connold = new OleDbConnection(connstrold);
        string strSQLold = "SELECT * FROM [Resources$]";
        OleDbCommand cmdold = new OleDbCommand(strSQLold, connold);
        OleDbDataAdapter daold = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdold);

        DataTable dtold = new DataTable();
        daold.Fill(dtold);
        // dataGridView1.DataSource = dtold;

        string connectionString = Application.StartupPath + "\\x_Lang_Res" + ".xls";
        string connstr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=" + connectionString + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstr);
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Chinese$]";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);

        // dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            string aa = row[1].ToString();
            foreach (DataRow rowold in dtold.Rows)
            {
                string old = rowold[3].ToString();
                if (!rowold[3].ToString().Contains(aa))
                {
                    richTextBox1.Text = aa + "\n\r";
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I have to select one column from Data Table 1 and check each row value of that column with data Table specific column if the valu of Data Table1's column is present in Data Table 2 column then it's OK . Otherwise i have to insert the values which are not present in Data Table 2 specific solumn in rich text box

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the result to the RTB.Text property each time.

```
if (!rowold[3].ToString().Contains(aa))
{
    richTextBox1.Text = aa + "\n\r";
}
```

You need to use += to append it.

```
 if (!rowold[3].ToString().Contains(aa))
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += aa + "\n\r";
    }
```

or even better use

RTB.AppendText( string.Format( "....." , a , b );

Comment: Basically i have to check that the specific value is present in column of data table or not ?

Comment: after appending my program goes to not responding state.

Comment: How many rows are you searching through? With you current code its going to take old rows X new rows loop passes to process. Also Appending directly to the RTB can be slow, you may be better using a StringBuilder to generate the text and pass it to the RTB once the process completes.

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing this part of the code

```
if (!rowold[3].ToString().Contains(aa))
{
    richTextBox1.Text = aa + "\n\r";
}
```

With this

```
if (aa!=old)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + aa + "\n\r";
}
```